# Is 不要在厨房里留下任何废物 the correct way of saying "do not leave any waste in the kitchen"?

Tags: translation

> Is 不要在厨房里留下任何废物 the correct way of saying "do not leave any waste in the kitchen"?

**Background:** I'm living in an apartment building in Taipei and there is a common kitchen on the first floor that I often use. Unfortunately, the other folks from the building who use the kitchen sometimes leave the trash in the kitchen after they're done instead of taking it out. I am thinking of sticking a small note on the refrigerator just to let them know not to leave waste in the kitchen. So my question is: Is 不要在厨房里留下任何废物 the correct way of saying "do not leave any waste in the kitchen"? Because that's what I got from google translate.

Comment: 根據我們的習慣，請用「垃圾」，而不是「廢物」。要留紙條，建議這樣寫：「各位室友：請保持廚房的整潔，不要留下任何垃圾。拜託了！謝謝！」

Comment: In spoken Chinese，废物 sounds more like describing someone as a loser, or useless piece of sh*t

Comment: I would prefer 废弃物 instead of 废物. Other words are fine. If the words are written on a sign / notice, use 请勿 instead of 不要 would be more formal.

Answer (score 2):

> 不要在廚房裡留下任何廢物

It is an acceptable translation of "do not leave any waste in the kitchen", you can use it just fine.

However, if you want to be a little more formal, you can write "please don't leave garbage in the kitchen" (請勿在厨房留下垃圾)

you don't need '裡' in '在廚房裡' ;  '在' alone in '在厨房' already covered the meaning of 'in'

you can remove '任何' in '任何垃圾' ;  just like 'dog' in 'no dog allowed' already meant 'all / any dog'

*Shorter note get the point across better. Just like '**不准泊車**' is better than '各位先生女士，在任何時間內都千萬不要在這個地點停泊任何車輛，包括摩托車及電動輪椅' (you can google translate this sentence) -- No one would read it.*

Comment: Yes, when you use Google translate, you can choose Traditional Chinese or  Simplified Chinese as the result language.

Answer (score 2):

I would say 垃圾 instead of 废物。 废物 sounds like "loser" sometimes....